# Paros Proxy detailed tutorials

Tags: security-testing, parosproxy

Can anyone suggest, where to find out detailed tutorials on Paros Proxy, I mean how to test application with paros. The information provided in concern site is not enough as it suggest only its use, I want like how to put SQL injection or XSS etc. Please suggest some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As such, paros proxy does not have documented tutorials. Have you given it a try first?

To get things started, first of all configure your browser for a proxy at localhost and a port.

Now you would have to set a local proxy in Paros Proxy from Tools -> Options -> Local Proxy. Set the address & port to the values which were set in the browser.

Go to the "Trap" tab in Paros and tick the checkboxes "Trap Request" and "Trap Response".

Load the url of the website you are testing on the browser. This http request will be intercepted in Paros Proxy. Now you can change the parameters as you like for testing.

I would also suggest you to try [ZAP Proxy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) as well. This has been forked out of Paros Proxy itself. It has a decent level of documentation as well.

Comment: Thanks Anuj for your valuable info. I am facing a problem, I have set all the proxy settings as necessary in my browser but the problem is that sometimes(not always) the website i am looking for does not get open even though paros proxy is running. please find out some solution. Thanks

Comment: Not too surprisingly I agree with the advice to use ZAP (I'm the ZAP project lead;)
Paros hasnt been updated for many years, while ZAP is being very actively developed. Its also completely free, with no paid for version.

If you do use ZAP then we have a user group (http://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users) where you can get answers to any problems you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the details from the following PDF:

http://www.sela.co.il/_Uploads/dbsAttachedFiles/paros_user_guide.pdf